# Не могу сделать так чтобы выводился 0 если не проходит тест в цикле.Прошу помочь

Tags: java

> Кинотеатр имеет n рядов, каждый ряд состоит из m посадочных мест (n и
> m не превышают 20). В двумерной матрице хранится информация о
> проданных билетах, цифра 1 означает, что билет на это место уже
> продан, цифра 0 означает, что место доступно. Вы хотите купить k
> билетов на соседние места в том же ряду. Выясните, можно ли это
> сделать.
>
> Формат входных данных
>
> На входе программа получает количество N рядов и m посадочных мест.
> Затем есть n строк, каждая из которых содержит m чисел (0 или 1),
> разделенных пробелами. Последняя строка содержит число k.
>
> Формат выходных данных
>
> Программа должна вывести номер ряда с k последовательными доступными
> местами. Если имеется несколько рядов с k доступными местами, выведите
> первый ряд с этими местами. Если такой строки нет, выведите число 0.
>
> Sample Input 1:
>
> ```
> 3 4
> 0 1 0 1
> 1 1 0 1
> 1 0 0 1
> 2
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Sample Input 2:
>
> ```
> 3 3
> 0 1 0
> 1 0 0
> 1 1 1
> 3
> ```
>
> Sample Output 2:
>
> ```
> 0
> ```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int[][] cinemaArr = new int[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                cinemaArr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int numbersOfTickets = sc.nextInt();


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < m - 1; j++) {
                if (counter == numbersOfTickets) {
                    System.out.println(i + 1);
                    break;
                } else if (cinemaArr[i][j] == 0 && cinemaArr[i][j] == cinemaArr[i][j + 1]) {
                    counter += 2;
                } else if (cinemaArr[i][j + 1] == 1) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос будет закрыт, так как на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Понял.Сейчас изменю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
          counter = (cinemaArr[i][j] == 0)? (counter + 1) : 0;
          if (counter == numbersOfTickets) {
            System.out.println(i + 1);
            return; 
          }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(0);
```

Comment: А что делает return в цикле? Он закрывает цикл полностью?

Comment: @fastrapier1 Он выходит из функции, прерывая все циклы, естественно.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы выводить ноль при отсутствии мест, можно использовать нулевой номер ряда. При успешном поиске он заменится на реальный номер.

```
int goodrow = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n && goodrow == 0; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (cinemaArr[i][j] == 1)
                 counter = 0;
            else {
                 counter += 1; 
                 if (counter == numbersOfTickets) {
                      goodrow = i + 1;
                      break;
                  }
              }
        }
  }
 println(goodrow);
```

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < n && goodrow == 0; i++) {`, `for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {`

Comment: Да, так компактнее, спасибо